# How to recover when SVN screws up repository paths

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository

In our SVN repository, we have a project for Eclipse. From the root of the project, we have "\bin\com\company\package". This folder should NOT be versioned, but it is. Upon further inspection using TortoiseSVN's repo browser from the bin folder, the repo browser opens up "\src"! How do I remove this reference to the bin folder and add it to the ignore list without royally screwing up our repository?

*NOTE* I primarily use Subclipse for SVN tasks related to the source code, but I occasionally use Tortoise for committing and updating files elsewhere in the repository.

Comment: Is it a SVN screw up or your / your team's screw up??

Comment: I can't see how it would be an error on our part. The repository does not have a record of \bin being versioned at all, but when I try to add it to the ignore list, Tortoise tells me that the folder is obstructed.

Comment: Also, deleting the bin folder from explorer does not fix the issue, and when I build the project the bin folder comes back with the Subversion bindings.

Comment: See my answer. Mostly guessing for your case, but I have observed that many times before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this happen in Eclipse / Subclipse build processes. Basically, you have copied some source files / resoucres from `\src` to `\bin` along with the `.svn` - and somehow having committed that, since the `.svn` metadata was from `\src`, it shows that in the repo browser. In short, you have copied your `\src` working copy ( a part of it that is) to `\bin` and committed there.

Modify the build process to ignore `.svn` in the copy process.

Comment: I'll try that, but none of the .java files make it into the bin folder, only the compiled class files.

Comment: @MetalSearGolid - Just make sure `.svn` is not inadvertently being copied

Comment: It was, I never thought to add *.svn to the exclusion rule, I figured Subclipse would be smart enough to handle that.